# Show that for every $n > 1$ there exist $n$ consecutive composite numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

So I am trying to prove  that for every $n > 1$ there exist $n$ consecutive composite numbers  but I do not know even how to start. This is a problem in analytic number theory.
Please can you help me solve this question in analytic number theory. Thank you

Comment: Consider the function called "factorial".  What properties of this function are relevant to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the numbers:

$$(n+1)! + 2, (n + 1)! + 3, ..., (n + 1)! + n + 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using multiples of $2$ and $3$:

If $n$ is odd then $3|3n$ and $2 | 3n + 1$.

If $n$ is even, then $2 | 3n + 2$ and $3|3n + 3$.